# dbt model for a bigquery sharded table on a year suffix that works with full refresh and incremental update

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, jinja2, dbt

I am struggling to find a way to manage a DBT model for a BigQuery set of tables that are sharded by year like:

1. `my_table_2023`
2. `my_table_2024`
3. and so on

This DBT model should select from a **source table** sharded the same way. I do not have control on this source table, I can only read from it.

I would like this DBT model to be general enough to be able to avoid creating new SQL files for each year, and also avoid to specify the year hard-coded inside the SQL in the DBT file.

I was first facing various errors related to Jinja syntax e.g.

```
14:40:54  Encountered an error:
Compilation Error in model xxx_2024 (aaa/xxx_2024.sql)
  'abc' is undefined. This can happen when calling a macro that does not exist. Check for typos and/or install package dependencies with "dbt deps".
```

that I managed to solve with a set of variables that are evaluated at runtime (see below), but still I am stuck on the part when I generalize the `_TABLE_SUFFIX` basically because I am trying to `CREATE` a table on the fly when not (yet) there:

```
15:37:15  Completed with 1 error and 0 warnings:
15:37:15  
15:37:15    Database Error in model xxx_MINUTES (aaa/xxx_MINUTES.sql)
  Syntax error: Unexpected keyword CREATE at [27:1]
  compiled Code at target/run/aaa/xxx_MINUTES.sql
```

See below the SQL code, I also would like to set partitions, clustering, force to require a partition filter

```sql
{{ config(
    materialized = 'incremental',
    incremental_strategy = 'insert_overwrite',
    partition_by = {
      "field": "day",
      "data_type": "DATE",
      "copy_partitions": false,
    },
    cluster_by = [
        "xyz", 
    ],
    require_partition_filter = true,
) }}

-- this is some macro code to determine the relevant daily partitions
{% set partitions_to_replace = get_partitions_to_replace_1d(partition_col="day") %}

{# table sharding dynamic details #}
{% set current_year = run_started_at.strftime("%Y") %}
{% set my_table_prefix = "my_table_MINUTES_" %}
{% set in_fqn_table_name = env_var('DBT_SOURCE_PROJECT') + "." + env_var('DBT_SOURCE_DATASET') + "." + my_table_prefix + current_year %}

{# output table with dynamically injected shard as year YYYY #}
{% set out_fqn_table_name = env_var('DBT_TARGET_PROJECT') + "." + env_var('DBT_TARGET_DATASET') + "." + 'out_MINUTES_' + current_year %}

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {{out_fqn_table_name}} AS
SELECT
  timestamp,
  [...]
  DATE(TIMESTAMP) AS day,
FROM {{ in_fqn_table_name }}
{% if is_incremental() %}
WHERE TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(timestamp, DAY) >= TIMESTAMP({{ partitions_to_replace[0] }})
{% endif %}
```

When I check the generated SQL code that throws the "syntax error" I can see that DBT already tries to create the table. So basically there are 2 nested `CREATE` statements: the outer one from DBT, the inner one from me: `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`.

Is it possible at all?

Can I retain both full-refresh and incremental update, but also generate tables on the fly based on the `current_year`?